# How to set up a local webDAV server for use with Goodreader on the ipad?

Tags: webdav

I need to know how to set up a local webDav server on my PC so that goodreader on ipad can automatically sync with it over the local wifi network?

I am really a rookie when it comes to setting up a web server and have tried various guides on the internet. I tried setting up a webdav server using IIS and forwarded the required ports and enabled webdav publishing but goodreader can find it in the local wifi network automatically nor is it able to connect even after manually entering the credendtials.

So i'll be really greateful if someone who has successfully setup a webdav server for use with goodreader can point me on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the BarracudaDrive WebDAV server which is designed for rookies :-)
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/

GoodReader/GoodSync is listed on the "compatible clients" list:
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/resources.lsp

Answer (score 1):

I know an old question, and no accepted answer, but for completeness:

We always used [Apache Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Tomcat/WebDav) for webdav.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Crush FTP Server (www.crushftp.com), which supports WebDAV and runs on Windows and other platforms, it's very simple to set up and should do the trick.

If you are looking for something more beefy, you can try Cornerstone MFT (www.cornerstoneMFT.com). Disclaimer...I work for this company.

If you are still running into problems after setting up the WebDAV server, make sure your Windows Firewall has opened port 80 to incoming traffic. You may also need to whitelist the WebDAV server process as a process that's allowed to access the Internet.

Usually the WebDAV server will listen on multiple IP addresses, LocalHost and then your generic IP address which most likely is something like 192.168.1.x or 192.168.2.x. The localhost address is your 'loopback' address and you can use that locally from the same Windows box to test to make sure the WebDAV server is working. The loopback address will bypass the firewall. Launch your WebDAV client and go to http ://localhost/ If that works, then try your IP address http ://192.168.1.x/ to verify that the WebDAV server is listening on an IP address that is accessible from other computers. The 192.168.1.x address will not bypass the firewall and this will let you know if the firewall is a problem. Then go to another computer, or your Mobile device, and use the 192.168.1.x address and you should be able to get to your WebDAV server. If you can't then it's most likely a Windows Firewall issue.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using Windows. WebDAV is not quite well supported by M$. Try Apache Web Server with mod_dav and mod_dav_fs.

Start reading here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dav.html

I haven't configured WebDAV on Apache before, I use a NAS which comes with a WebDAV server on its own. Apache Web Server might not look so easy to configure , but with a bit of perseverance, I think you could make it work. Good luck!